# Specify decimal places in r plot text?

Tags: r, plot, label, decimalformat

I tried to format the label of my regression curve created in the base graphics system.  Basically, this label extracts the slope, the intercept and the r-square values from variables.  An example is as below:

```
plot(rnorm(10), type = "n", xlim = c(0, 100), ylim = c(0, 100))
text(x = 0, y = 100, adj = c(0, NA), bquote(paste(y == .(a) * x + .(b), ", R"^2 == .(r2))), cex = 0.7)
```

However, this generated a label that did not look very smart:

```
y = 1.159019x+-1.537708, R<sup>2</sup>=0.7924927
```

What I would like is to round the figures to the second decimal place, i.e.,

```
y = 1.16x-1.54, R<sup>2</sup>=0.79
```

I have looked it up in both help documents for `text()` and `bquote()` but did not find much useful information.

I have also tried to wrap the `.(a)`, `.(b)` and `.(r2)` in `format()` with the parameter `nsmall = 2`, but it did not work.

Could someone kindly help me with this?  Many thanks in advance!

ps. I think there is a hidden quest in my question.  In the above example, `b` is negative.  I know I could probably leave out the `"+"` operator in my expression to just use the negative sign of `b` to join my equation.  However, what if I do not know the sign of `b` in advance?  Is there a clever way of forming the label without checking this with an `if()` and then write two very slightly different versions of `text()`?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For specifying the number of digits, use `round(a, digits=2)`. However, you can also use `sprintf` to deal with both the number of digits and the + or - in your equation: e.q. %+3.2f, where `%` forces the + or - sign in the equation and `3.2f` controls the number of digits, so this solves both your issues. I found a solution for the superscript problem in `sprintf`  [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Superscripts-and-rounding-td899133.html): "B2 is the hex code for UTF-8 character = ^2 and \U is a control sequence that will call that character."

```
# data and regression
set.seed(1)
y = 1:10+rnorm(10)
x = 1:10
fit = lm(y~x)
b = coef(fit)[1]
a = coef(fit)[2]
r2 = summary(fit)$r.squared

# plot data and regression
plot(x, y)
abline(fit, col=2)

# add text to plot with legend() for convenient placement
legend('topleft', title='option 1', legend=sprintf("y = %3.2fx %+3.2f, R\UB2 = %3.2f", a, b, r2), bty='n', cex=0.7)

# if you prefer a pretty space between plus/minus and b:
if( b<0) {my_sign = ' - '; b = -b} else { my_sign= ' + '}
legend('bottomright', title='option 2', legend=sprintf("y = %3.2f x %s %3.2f, R\UB2 = %3.2f", a, my_sign, b, r2), bty='n', cex=0.7)
```

[image: display equation on plot]

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive answer (both solutions and suggestions of using `round()` and `legend()` - those were brilliant!). Also thanks for including the original superscript solution - I was surprised how repetitive my question was to that one - oops! ;-P I like the use of `%+` in `sprintf()` for dealing with the sign. Originally I had slightly more complex requirements (both `x` and `y` had text subscripts, eg. "[NO2]subscript-urban"), which was why I used the clumsy `bquote()` with nested `paste()` for formatting.  Guess an `if()` is unavoidable for the sign in this way?